# Google credential json file on Serverless AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, serverless-framework, dialogflow-es

I try to use DialogFlow (API.AI or Google Cloud Dialogflow API) on my [serverless](https://serverless.com/framework/) project but the problem that I couldn't find any solution for pushing google credential json file to serverless side. I followed [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) (it's on google cloud website) and It works correctly on my local but not on lambda. I even tried to copy the file from webpack but It still doesn't work. For DialogFlow, I'm using [dialogflow v2 nodejs library](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-nodejs-client-v2).

***--- edit***

I'm getting this error on lambda which is related to not find the json file I think because I'm not using this module (dialogFlow is using)

*(rejection id: 2): Error: Cannot find module '/var/task/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v48-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node'*

***--- edit end***

node.js: 6.x

serverless: 1.26

====

serverless.yml

```
service: test-dialogflow-svc

plugins:
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-plugin-common-excludes
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-offline-scheduler

package:
  individually: true
  include:
    - googleCredentials.json

custom:
  webpackIncludeModules: true
  serverless-offline:
    port: 3000

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  stage: dev
  region: eu-west-2
  memorySize: 128
  timeout: 5
  environment:
    GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: './googleCredentials.json'

functions:
  hello:
    handler: src/handlers/helloworld.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: hello
          method: get
    package:
      include:
        - googleCredentials.json
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const slsw = require('serverless-webpack');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const WebpackPluginCopy = require('webpack-plugin-copy');

module.exports = {
  entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  target: 'node',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.ts', '.tsx']
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [ // I tried to copy file with webpack as well
     new WebpackPluginCopy([{
       copyPermissions: true,
       from: './googleCredentials.json'
     }])
  ],
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '.webpack'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  }
};
```

Comment: "It works correctly on my local but not on lambda." - what errors do you get?

Comment: have you copied your './googleCredentials.json' file when uploading to your serverless platform?

Comment: hey @rsp, I'm getting this error: "(rejection id: 2): Error: Cannot find module '/var/task/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v48-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node'" I also updated the question with this info

Comment: @matthewayne, I didn't try it honestly because I'm trying to find solution with serverless framework. I don't want to upload lambda function manually. But I will test to just see the result ;)

Comment: @the_bluescreen could you explain how you solved the issue with the Google credential .json file?
The second error you are seeing is caused by the gRPC node native c++ module. 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/nodejs-packages-in-lambda/
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node

Comment: Hey @Giorgio, I created a custom pipe for webpack to copy the credential file to each handler folder before uploading to AWS. Basically, You need to add that file to each handler folder. I realized that hold that in parent project folder doesn't mean anything for serverless. It doesn't send it without copy files inside of the handler folder.

Comment: thanks @the_bluescreen. I added an answer for the .json credentials part and for the gRPC c++ compilation module. It's usually a better approach to open a new question on Stackoverflow rather than editing the previous one with a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is made of two parts:

1. Copying the Google credentials .json file in the serverless .zip bundle
2. Compile the gRPC c++ native node module for amazon-linux or use the REST JSON API

1) It's possible to copy the Google credentials .json file into the .zip bundle using the [serverless-webpack plugin](https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack) and the [webpack-plugin-copy](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin).

*serverless.yml*

```
...

plugins:
  - serverless-webpack

...
```

*webpack.config.js*

```
...

const WebpackPluginCopy = require('webpack-plugin-copy');

module.exports = {

  ...

  plugins: [
    new WebpackPluginCopy([{
      copyPermissions: true,
      from: `./googleCredentials.json`,
     }])
  ],

};
```

2) The DialogFlow node client use this [gRPC client](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node) which has a [c++ native module dependency](https://medium.com/@marcinbaraniecki/extending-node-js-with-native-c-modules-63294a91ce4). This is also true for all other node clients for Google Cloud Platform products like [Datastore](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-datastore).

You will need to build the native c++ modules on amazon-linux instance on your computer through Docker or an EC2.

[C++ Addons as AWS Lambda functions](https://nodeaddons.com/c-addons-as-aws-lambda-functions/)

[Using Packages and Native nodejs Modules in AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/nodejs-packages-in-lambda/)

**REST JSON API instead of gRPC**

Since native c++ module are annoying to build and all the Google Cloud Platform node clients also add ~30mb to your serverless .zip bundle you might want to avoid the gRPC client and find/write a HTTP client that calls the [REST JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/) instead. JSON over HTTP has a higher latency than gRPC but this is not significant unless you have many layers of micro services calling each other.

In the future the node gRPC clients might work without c++ modules using javascript and weight far less than 30mb but at the time of writing there is no sign of commitment except for an [alpha stage submodule on the gRPC node client](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node).